macbook pro battery is not charging
I have a macbook pro 2017 with Chip intel.
And i have the issue with the battery, its plugged In but the charge keep in 1% and a message "the battery is not charging " and if i unplugged the mac turns off
The battery health its normal
I tried with the Reset the SMC but nothing work.
https://imgur.com/a/Mv7SUlp

A 7 year old battery probably just reached the end of its lifespan and needs to be replaced.

@nohillside Hi, i checked the cycles and has 94, also i know the battery was changed

When was the battery replaced before? Was it a genuine Apple battery? Ultimately, if the battery isn't charging (and you've ruled out cables and power supply), then it's not a healthy battery. Either that or the power management unit is broken.

You've tried a different charger?

Welcome to Ask Different.  We have dozens of questions covering what to do when a battery doesn’t charge. What is your end goal here? I’ve linked to 4 questions that show some good research and if you edit this to show where you need help past these posts, we can reopen this if needed for a new answer.
